# Правильно ли написано предложение или нет? Есть ли ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Как думаете, у кого сегодня день рождения? Правильно, у меня!*

Comment: Выглядит правильным

Answer (score 1):

***Как думаете, у кого сегодня день рождения? Правильно, у меня!***

Всё правильно, в предложении нет ошибок. Стиль разговорный, но грамматика вполне ясная.

Первое предложение **сложноподчиненное с придаточным изъяснительным,** запятая ставится перед союзным словом "у кого".

Второе предложение **неполное**, сравнить: Правильно, день рождения сегодня у меня. Запятая ставится в **бессоюзном сложном предложении**.